# How to add action to UINavigation bar button

Tags: swift, xcode

Pardon me if this question doesn't make much sense, am new to iOS. I was wondering where and how I could set an action to a UINavigation bar button that appears across several view controllers? Is this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it programatically using this, then you have to call this method to create your button and action on every view or just create a super class for your views to setup your buttons and actions.

```
let menuButton = UIButton()
        menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "menuAction"), for: UIControlState())
        menuButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 30)
        menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
        let menuButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        menuButtonItem.customView = menuButton

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButtonItem
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure how to set actions with a UINavigation bar button but if what you're trying to accomplish is a menu with actionable buttons you can try `UIToolbar` and then add `Bar Button Item`s to which you can assign actions by the good ol' control drag from Main.storyboard to your desired location on your code.

Hope it helps!